# Some bibliography of an introduction to Bayesian Data Analysis

Tags: bayesian, curve-fitting

I'm doing a PhD in astrophysics and astrodynamics. Ive coursed a math degree but I'm not familiarized with statistics and analysis data. In the thesis I'm doing a lot of bayesian analysis data is required to modeling some observations and so on. Can you please recommend to me some bibliography that could help an amateur like me? Something like an introduction or whatever.

This is an article im trying to understand, for example. The part of the Bayesian model escapes me.

https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.0752

Comment: What exactly don't you understand about the article? Bayes factors extend fairly naturally from frequentist based testing, just using Bayes theorem to construct a "probability" for (the) null and alternative hypothes(e/i)s. "Bayesian and Frequentist Regression methods" by Wakefield, chapters 2 and 3 have a great, more verbose discussion on the subject.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learn Bayesian inference applied to astronomy / astrophysics?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/237178/learn-bayesian-inference-applied-to-astronomy-astrophysics) or http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/125/what-is-the-best-introductory-bayesian-statistics-textbook or http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7351/bayesian-statistics-tutorial